# PregMatch . space and @?

Tags: preg-match

Can someone tell me, what's wrong in this code:

```
if ((!preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9 \.\s]", $username)) || (!preg_match("[a-zA-Z0-9 \.\s]", $password)));
exit("result_message=Error: invalid characters");
}
```

??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things are wrong. I assume that the code you are looking for is:

```
if (preg_match('~[^a-z0-9\h.]~i', $username) || preg_match('~[^a-z0-9\h.]~i', $password))
    exit('result_message=Error: invalid characters');
```

What is wrong in your code?

the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9 \.\s]` is false for multiple reasons:

- a regex pattern in PHP must by enclosed by delimiters, the most used is `/`, but as you can see, I have choosen `~`. Example: `/[a-zA-Z \.\s]/`
- the character class is strange because it contains a space and the character class `\s` that contains the space too. IMO, to check a username or a password, you only need the space and why not the tab, but not the carriage return or the line feed character! You can remove `\s` and let the space, or you can use the `\h` character class that matches all horizontal white spaces. `/[a-zA-Z\h\.]/` *(if you don't want to allow tabs, replace the `\h` by a space)*
- the dot has no special meaning inside a character class and doesn't need to be escaped: `/[a-zA-Z\h.]/`
- you are trying to verify a whole string, but your pattern matches a single character! In other words, the pattern checks only if the string contains at least an alnum, a space or a dot. If you want to check all the string you must use a quantifier `+` and anchors for the start `^` and the end `$` of the string. Example `∕^[a-zA-Z0-9\h.]+$/`
- in fine, you can shorten the character class by using the case-insensitive modifier `i`: `/^[a-z0-9\h.]+$/i`

But there is a faster way, instead of negate with `!` your preg_match assertion and test if all characters are in the character range you want, you can only test if there is one character you don't want in the string. To do this you only need to negate the character class by inserting a `^` at the first place:

```
preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\h.]/i', ...
```

*(Note that the `^` has a different meaning inside and outside a character class. If `^` isn't at the begining of a character class, it is a simple literal character.)*

Comment: +1 constructive, nice presented and complete answer.